# Python group by one column then group by the "month" from another column of date datatype

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to do a grouping by the column "CUSTOMER_ID" and then for each customer ID evaluate the monthly sum of debs. So I need to apply group by two columns where the second column must be months from the "REPORT_DATE" column which is of date data type. I grouped by CUSTOMER_ID and then wanted to group by the "month", however, I cannot apply group by to a GroupBy Object(as it is not a DataFrame anymore).

```
df.groupby(['CUSTOMER_ID'], as_index=False) 
['DEBT_AMOUNT'].sum().sort_values()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['month']=df.date.dt.month
df.groupby(['CUSTOMER_ID', 'month'], as_index=False)['DEBT_AMOUNT'].sum().sort_values()
```